# gkrellm: can you display a chart of the memory usage?

Tags: memory, monitoring, debugging, out-of-memory, gkrellm

#### little background:

I had some processes on a machine with 128GB memory that reported python memory allocation errors (the machine ran out of memory). My code only uses like 1-3GB memory... so I should not be getting these sorts of python memory allocation errors.

So I wanted to look into the memory usage by looking at memory usage over time with a chart.

- look for when the machine uses up all of it's memory
- is it sudden or gradual (maybe memory leak)
- look for trends that happen over time... (maybe it always happens once a day at the same time)

I got gkrellm and was excited to use it. It has great cpu, networking, disk charts. But for some reason the memory is not a chart... the memory instead is just a slider-widget representing 0% to 100% usage... which is not so useful.

### gkrellm: can you display a chart of the memory usage, yes/no? if yes, how?

Comment: I can probably use `gnome-system-monitor` and change the sampling period to 1 or 10 minutes. But I asked the question because I wanted to use `gkrellm`.

Comment: I wish there was a plugin that could graph the output of any shell command. We could ask it to plot the output of `awk '/^Active:/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: Oh, I have found a plugin called [gkrellm-fchart](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/gkrellm-fchart.html) that can read data from a file, but it looks like I must run the data collection command independently.